# Running Mongodb Alternatives other than homebrew-brew

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, express

Im running mongodb using homebrew-brew. Is there a more efficient way to run it within vs code or is this the only option or the easiest option?

Answer (score 0):

Use the official **mongo docker image** to create a new container and use it in your application as normal mongo instance.